# remove event listener ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

With jQuery I create an ajax call wit GET method. This request is triggered if the user scrolls to the bottom. If the ajax call is running i want to remove the scroll listener. If the ajax call is success add the scroll function. I tried this with unbind but this does not work.

Is there anybody who can help me ?

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            $(window).unbind('scroll');
            //ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "result.php",
                data: {
                    'offset': flag,
                    'limit':12
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('.gallery').append(data);
                flag += 12;
            }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: try `$(window).off('scroll');`

Comment: @AlivetoDie That would only work if the event listener was attached with `.on()`

Comment: You should be able to use `window.onscroll = null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name the function executed in the eventListener and use `.on()` / `.off()` to remove the listeners:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", windowScroll);


function windowScroll(ev) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    $(window).off('scroll', windowScroll); // remove the listener on scroll
    //ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "result.php",
      data: {
        'offset': flag,
        'limit': 12
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.gallery').append(data);
        flag += 12;
        $(window).on("scroll", windowScroll); // re-attach it when the request is finished
      }
    });
  }
};
```